Keep list indices between different minipage environments
This is the code I have at the moment:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage{tikz, scalerel, pict2e, tkz-euclide}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{rojo}{RGB}{215,20,103}
\definecolor{celeste}{RGB}{32,210,255}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{55,211,102}

\begin{document}
    % Ejercicio 1
    \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Un péndulo ideal, formado por una cuerda de longitud $L=0.8m$ y un cuerpo de masa $m_1=0.25kg$, se deja caer desde una posición horizontal. Cuando llega al punto más bajo de su trayectoria choca pláticamente con otro cuerpo de masa $m_2=4.m_1$, que tiene una velocidad horizontal constante $v_2=3\frac{m}{s}$ en la dirección indicada.\\
            Considere que: Las masas son puntuales y no hay rozamiento.
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item ¿Se conserva alguna magnitus? En caso afirmativo explicar la causa.
                \item Deetermine la velocidad del cuerpo 1 justo antes de chocar con el cuerpo 2.
                \item Calcule la velocidad de las masas justo después del choque.
                \item ¿A qué altura llega el péndulo después del choque plástico?
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            % Grid
            \draw[white] (0,0) grid (6,5);
            % Triángulo del techo
            \draw  (0.5,5) -- (3.5,5);
            \draw  (1,5) -- (2, 4);
            \draw (2,4) -- (3,5);
            % Pelota 1
            \fill (2,4) circle [radius=0.1];
            \draw (2,4) -- (5,4);
            \draw (5.5,4) circle [radius=0.5] node[above] {1};
            % Largo
            \draw[Stealth-Stealth] (2,3) -- (5,3) node[midway, below] {$L$};
            % Pelota 2
            \draw[dotted] (2,4) -- (2,0);
            \draw (1.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.5] node[above] {2};
            \draw[-Stealth] (1.5,0.5) -- (3,0.5) node[above] {$v_2$};
            % Piso
            \draw (0,0) -- (4,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    
    
    % Ejercicio 2   
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Un cilindro de masa M y radio R está dispuesto como se muestra en la figura.\\
            El cilindro cuelga del techo mediante un corón ideal que está enrollado alrededor del mismo. Desde un eje liso en el centro de la polea cuelga una masa m.
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Calcule el módulo de la aceleración del centro de masa del disco.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
            \draw[white] (0,0) grid (4,6);
            % techo
            \fill[gray] (0, 6) rectangle (3, 5);
            \draw[line width=2pt] (0,5) -- (3,5);
            % circulo
            \fill[lightgray](2,3) circle [radius=1];
            \draw[] (2,3) circle [radius=1] node[above] {$M, R$};        
            % cuerdas
            \draw (1,3) -- (1,5);
            \draw (2,3) -- (2,1);
            % caja
            \fill[gray] (1.5,0.5) rectangle (2.5,1);
            \draw[] (1.5,0.5) rectangle (2.5,1) node[midway] {\textbf{$m$}};
            % eje
            \draw[-Stealth] (3.5, 5) -- (3.5, 3) node[midway, right] {$\vec{g}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}

I am wondering if there is any way of maintaining the indices of the lists between minipages so that I don't have to number them manually.

welcome! must you use enumerate or is enumitem an option? enumitem allows you to create continuous series where the numbering resumes automatically.

can you please remove code not required by your question? tikz seems egregious here, for instance, since a simple ABC would appear to do as well. or use \includegraphics{example-image} or, if that's too boring, \includegraphics{cow}, which is positively exciting in comparison.

If you can use enumitem rather than enumerate, this is straightforward. The shortlabels option enables you to use the enumerate syntax to specify labels.
I've also tidied up the code to get rid of the bad box warnings. I reduced the size of your minipages because if you have one of width \textwidth and one of width 0.65\textwidth with 0.5cm plus space between them, you exceed the total width of the text block by a considerable margin.
For the sake of the example, I minimised both packages and code by using standard images available with any TeX installation.
There are various ways to achieve the desired result (with or without enumitem). You could set up a custom list, but if this is the only tweak you need to make, just using
\begin{enumerate}[series=<name of series>]

and then
\begin{enumerate}[resume=<name of series>]

is an easy and transparent solution.

\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
  \begin{enumerate}[series=twins]
    \item Un péndulo ideal, formado por una cuerda de longitud $L=0.8m$ y un cuerpo de masa $m_1=0.25kg$, se deja caer desde una posición horizontal. Cuando llega al punto más bajo de su trayectoria choca pláticamente con otro cuerpo de masa $m_2=4.m_1$, que tiene una velocidad horizontal constante $v_2=3\frac{m}{s}$ en la dirección indicada.\\
      Considere que: Las masas son puntuales y no hay rozamiento.
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item ¿Se conserva alguna magnitus? En caso afirmativo explicar la causa.
        \item Deetermine la velocidad del cuerpo 1 justo antes de chocar con el cuerpo 2.
        \item Calcule la velocidad de las masas justo después del choque.
        \item ¿A qué altura llega el péndulo después del choque plástico?
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.5cm}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-5mm}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{cow}
\end{minipage}


% Ejercicio 2
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
  \begin{enumerate}[resume=twins]
    \item Un cilindro de masa M y radio R está dispuesto como se muestra en la figura.

      El cilindro cuelga del techo mediante un corón ideal que está enrollado alrededor del mismo. Desde un eje liso en el centro de la polea cuelga una masa m.
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Calcule el módulo de la aceleración del centro de masa del disco.
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.5cm}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-5mm}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{mill}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}

Off-topic:

don't end lines with \\  except in special environments such as tabular, array etc.; use a blank line followed by \noindent if you don't want indentation for a particular case (or load parskip if you never want indentation).
don't use $$...$$ for display maths with the LaTeX format; use \[...\] instead.

[I think the maths was not really meant to be in your MWE as you had \end{document} before it, but probably it is in your actual document - or something similar.]
